# .Net and SQL Server Diagnostics

Tags: .net, sql, diagnostics

Our company has many .Net applications on many servers which utilize many different SQL Servers. We do not have a clear idea of what is using what. It would be great to get a full picture of what's going on down to the smallest details. Especially important is to know what App is connecting to what Database.

Idea's so far have been to aggregate many different log types such as: SQL Profile, IIS Logs, and Perfmon.

What will give me the details I need?  Am I overlooking the logs I currently have at hand? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Starting to look at SysInternal's from Microsoft:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx

Comment: The folks over at SuperUser.com might also be able to answer this.

Comment: I'm starting to look at the SysInternal's suite that's available from Microsoft.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx

Answer (score 3):

One easy thing you can do is make sure your connection strings take advantage of the "Application Name" element.

```
Server=OurSqlServer;Database=AppDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=Our Application Name
```

When you look at things like profiling this will be much easier to differentiate.

Another good practice would be to ensure each app is connecting with it's own set of credentials.

Comment: We've had several transitions over the years.  Meaning some app's have encrypted registry entries, and other's have even worse... embedded in the source code.

We have been using these practices moving forward. Our SQL team is much stronger now, and enforcement is fairly strict.

Answer (score 2):

Can you possibly consider existing third-party apps?

Check out Quest's [Spotlight on SQL Server](http://www.quest.com/spotlight-on-sql-server-enterprise/) product - it would do all you're looking for, I believe.

Marc

*(Disclaimer: I used to work for Quest almost 10 years ago, but not on this tool and not in this business area. I have no connection to Quest at this time, other than being a "Quest alumni")*

Comment: Third party apps would be considered as long as the price is right. But the preferred approach would be to use what exists on the servers.